# Corrupted files

Tags: hard-drive, backup, data-recovery, data-corruption

While installing something, I used the `chown` command the wrong way (changed permissions for basically all directories) and had to reinstall Ubuntu. Before that I had a big problem with making a backup of the important data on an external hard drive. I somehow thought I managed to do that in recovery mode (at least I can see all the data on the HD).

However, most of the files somehow got corrupted and I can not open them anymore. It seems like they were converted to some kind of binary format.

Just some exemplary error messages:

```
opening a .png: "Fatal error reading PNG image file: Not a PNG file"

Opening .py with gedit: "The file you opened has some invalid characters...."
```

Its weird that:

1. Not all of the data on the drive are corrupted.
2. Not even all of the backed up data is corrupted, for example the highest level files are still fine.

Can anyone give me some support on this? There are some really important codes which I would not like to miss.

Comment: Unmount the drive and use `sudo badblocks /dev/sdxx` replacing `sdxx` by the right partition name. If nothing turns up, your drive is OK but the backup has failed.

Comment: This is running right now. Also did ckhdsk on Windows which showed no errors on the drive. After analyzing which data is corrupted it seems like only the part of the data i copied with rsync is corrupted. The part of the data i copied with cp seems to be intact. In case the drive is fine. Is there any chance to recover that data?

Comment: Nothing showed up with badblocks

Comment: Can you remember if the `rsync` command ended correctly? Obviously it's not supposed to write anything else than an exact copy of the source, and in fact I've never seen it do anything else. Is there a pattern to the corruptions in e.g. your `py` files?

Comment: I remember that I terminated the copying once because I noticed that I do not have to backup all of them and restarted the rsync again. So That would at least be a non correctly ending for once. As a pattern I can only say that the files seem to have the same size as they should have, but they are not readable. Or what do you mean/expect as a pattern? Thanks for your interest so far btw